# Are bots useful for filling a Team Fortress 2 Server?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I've started my own Team Fortress server and it's been very quiet Are bots (the official Valve bots) helpful or unhelpful in this situation? Most players don't seem to like playing with bots (even if it's just until the server fills) but leaving the server empty seems like an even worse idea.

Edit: For the record. My server is totally honest about using bots. The bot quota is set low so that players have something to do while the server fills and the Valve behaviour is kept - that is the server has a "bots" tag and the Bots appear with "Bot" for ping. Fake players are an immediate Blacklist for me.

Comment: Are you talking about the "fake" bots that show up under "players" but don't actually participate in the game, or the Valve-created bots that they have been developing?

Comment: Valve bots, updated the question.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18325/how-do-i-avoid-tf2-servers-loaded-with-bots

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to the catch 22 problem of getting a social service up and running. People will come back if people come back... how to start the cycle to begin with?

Most server farms fill in the maps with bots, without advertising this in the server browser. That's really awful, especially because you tend to have dumb, but *accurate* enemies. Bots can be remarkably human like (they don't have to chat after all), until they fail utterly (I screamed at my teammates stuck in the spawn room in stage 3 of cp_egypt for half an hour before realizing the obvious truth.) you can usually tell those servers from others because they have 23/24 players online, always, to make the game (and donating) inviting.

So the niche of filling a server with bots is filled, and so are the 24/7 servers niche, the achievements niche and the idle niche. What TF2 needs is more actual TF2 servers.

I have been regularly playing on the servers generously run by the ATF clan. Why?

- An actual map rotation! It's small but varied enough to keep things interesting and changed periodically. It features a mix of stock and custom maps.
- No voting. Clan members have access to some commands to scramble or advance in the rotation and that's it. No map is allowed to be dragged out past its welcome.
- Actual human beings! With as little life as I have! And they're better than me! And they actually play for the map objectives! And they use voice chat!

The server is run in the US, so I have 170 ping. This is quite annoying (using any  shotgun or melee weapon is an exercise in frustration) but do I really care? Shit, I'm actually playing the damn game. That's all I care about.

Now. What can *you* do to make a successful server?

- Bring your server. The server must be well configured so that it can't be hostaged by people mistaking 2fort as an excuse for mindless DM. This is crucial.
- Bring your rules. Be strict about actually playing ghe game: no farming, no idling, no trading, no crafting. That's not your niche. You want to play the damn game.
- Bring your friends. Bring people that share your vision and passion, and with which you have fun playing the damn game with. Enable alltalk for banter if you want to. Give those people access to the server, so that only trusted members can nextmap, callvote or scramble. Optionally, encourage everyone to use voice chat by using voice chat yourself.

That's it. Now you have a decent vanilla server where you're playing the damn game with your friends. Embrace your guests and make them want to come back, not for access to a clan or servers or whatever, but because you're playing the damn game. Then *play the damn game.*

Congratulations! You'll have built your little loyal happy community on the internet.

Comment: +1 for finding a clan server to play on. I'm an S.T.N.O man myself.

Comment: You don't like voting? :O  OCR's servers have voting because people kept complaining about the map rotation... and customs won't appear in votes unless someone nominates it first.

Comment: @Raven What name do you play with on the STNO server?

Comment: @Dave Lobstah Rage Fist

Comment: @powerlord Voting to scramble is fine in my view, but I'd rather have a reasonable map rotation than letting people do popularity contests on maps.

Comment: @Raven Ah, then I know you well since I'm an STNO member :).  Either way, I agree with badp's advice regarding finding a clan that you find fun to play with and become a regular. I greatly prefer the social aspect of gaming over the competitive aspect of gaming.  Our server has alltalk enabled and is much more conversation-oriented and laid back than other servers I've played on.  People's preferences are different, so YMMV.  Either way, find a server you like, play on it a while, get to know the other people you're playing with, and enjoy yourself :)

Comment: @Dave Sounds like the kind of server I'd love playing on. I must favourite it! :)

Comment: @badp I didn't know the community rules regarding self-promotion, so I refrained from posting the IP.  It shouldn't be too hard to find either way :)

Comment: @Fail badp - I'm not affiliated with the server, so I can give you the IP without it being self-promotion! 205.234.166.21:27015

Comment: @Dave It's okay, I grabbed it from your clan's website anyway.