# How can I host a TF2 server with idle bots being advertised in the browser?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'd like to host a TF2 server with bots. By default, there are no bots if I do not join, which is cool, since the server can idle. However, there are no bots advertised if I look up the game in my TF2 browser. I'd like to have a server with these properties:

- The bots should idle if no humans are on the server.
- Yet, the bots should be displayed in the TF2 browser (so they count as bots in the bot column) - even if they are in an idle state.

Is this possible, and how?

Note: It is not my idea to pretend that the bots are players, I just want to display the current number of bots in the bot count "column". Bots are easy to identify by their name in TF2, so there should be no confusion.

Comment: You want to host a server that has zero players, as having players?

Comment: @fbueckert Correct.

Comment: That seems dishonest. I'm not a TF2 player, but there must be some popular tag or other way for servers to advertise that they have bots.

Comment: So are you just asking us to tell you a dishonest way of tricking people into connecting your server when it's empty?

You realize people will just leave when they realize it's a sever of bots, right?

Comment: I think his goal is to have the bots idle when no humans are present so they aren't wasting resources killing each other for no reason.  He wants them to display as players so that human players can know they won't be bored if they join.

Comment: No it is not my idea to pretend that the bots are players, I just want to show the current number of (bots+players)...

Comment: So are you wanting the bots to show up in the "Bot" count, or are you wanting them to show up in the "Player" count? As far as I'm aware, there's no reason that they shouldn't be in the bot count, but having never hosted a TF2 server, I don't know.

Comment: @Unionhawk I can not find a "bot count" for tf2.

Comment: Related, not the same: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18325/how-do-i-avoid-tf2-servers-loaded-with-bots

Comment: @Unionhawk Thanks, now I could rewrite the question. Still, my server shows zero bots when in idle mode, so I think the question can still be answered.

Comment: isnt this illegal because it is idling?

Comment: Why not put "6v6 Bot Fill" or whatever is appropriate in the title of your server?

Comment: @AustinMohr If people search by sorting in the bot column, they won't find my server.